# How do I add content for warning macro using storage format?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api, confluence-macros

I'm creating a markdown to confluence tool (using python markdown). I'm having an issue adding content for the warning macro.

The following creates the warning box with the title, but the content is missing.

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="warning">
  <ac:parameter ac:name="title">Do Not Modify This Page</ac:parameter>
  <ac:rich-text-body><p>
  This page is generated by a script. Any changes made
  here will be erased the next time this page is
  generated.
  </p></ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

The [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/info-tip-note-and-warning-macros-51872369.html) for the warning macro don't specify what should be used.

When I edit the warning box in the ui and get `body.storage` for the page this is what is returned.

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"warning\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"3520f15e-e8af-4b26-bf94-4dbc226d8284\">
  <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">Do Not Modify This Page</ac:parameter>
  <ac:rich-text-body><p>blah frickin blah</p></ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

I have tried replacing `<ac:rich-text-body>` with `nothing`, `plain-text-body`, `body`, `content` and a few others I can't remember. None of these have worked.

Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the macro-id to the definition made it work.

```
  <ac:structured-macro ac:name="warning" ac:macro-id="3520f15e-e8af-4b26-bf94-4dbc226d8284">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="title">Do Not Modify This Page</ac:parameter>
    <ac:rich-text-body><p>
    This page is generated by a script. Any changes made
    here will be erased the next time this page is
    generated.
    </p></ac:rich-text-body>
  </ac:structured-macro>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me without a macro-id:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="note"><ac:parameter ac:name="icon">true</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body><h3>Auto-generated page. Do not edit in Confluence; edits will be overwritten!</h3></ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

Where my REST API put request had JSON of `{'body: {'storage': {'value': STUFF_HERE}}}` where `STUFF_HERE` was some HTML starting with the note macro I showed above. The JSON also included other stuff like page version number of course, I just omitted that stuff for brevity.